# Select rows with cursor once only

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a situation in PL/SQL where my procedure is called every minute by a job. The code is as below

```
procedure ExecuteProc is
CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT *
    FROM test6
    where processed = 'N';
BEGIN

--  Make all rows selected in the cursor processed 'Y' but 
--  the cursor below would fail

for rec in c1
loop
--    some proccessing which takes 5 -6 minutes
   delete from test6 where id = rec.id;
end loop;
END;
```

example data in test6 table

```
id  processed
1    N
2    N
3    N
```

When the procedure is called the first time, id 1,2 and 3 are picked up by the procedure in the cursor. Please note the rows also exist in the table test6 unless each id's processing is finished. Which means when the procedure is called the second time in the next minute, the procedure picks up 1,2 and 3 again. How can I avoid this? I was thinking of making the 'processed' field 'Y' somehow but (see my comment in the code where cursor would fail).

Please help

Comment: First, there is at least suspect that the job is done once per minute when the action which performs takes 5-6 minutes. In my opinion, this will lead to many of locking the session, and the waiting time will increase. Is there way to optimize the "- some proccessing Which takes 5 -6 minutes"? What's the process?

Answer (score 2):

Try to lock the line before deleting:

```
procedure ExecuteProc is
CURSOR c1 IS
SELECT *
FROM test6
where processed = 'N';
BEGIN

--  Make all rows selected in the cursor processed 'Y' but 
--  the cursor below would fail

  for rec in c1
  loop
    if rec.processed <> 'L' then


    --    some proccessing which takes 5 -6 minutes
    update test6 set processed ='L' where id = rec.id; -- lock status
    delete from test6 where id = rec.id;
    end if;
   end loop;
END;
```

You will be sure that, you delete the right one.
But you have to optimize, the call of the procedure behind your processing.

Comment: I think this will break down in multi-threading because of the old MUTEX (mutual exclusion) problem. You have no guarantee that two threads will not enter the loop for the same row and the big processing is done twice for the same row. You would have to guarantee the row is marked by only one thread BEFORE processing it, this can only be achieved by NOWAIT or SKIP LOCKED...

Answer (score 2):

If you are on 11g you are in Luck :-) you can Use SELECT FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED in the Cursor - then you are guaranteed that two threads will never get the same row on a fetch!

The RIGHT WAY to do this in Oracle would be Advanced Queueing - since this will solve ALL YOUR PROBLEMS, provides synchronization und parallel execution and other benefits...

Before Oracle 11 and without Advanced Queuing (if you really want to code it yourself...) You can do it like this:
(The bits marked with autonomous transaction have to be called in a separate method as an autonomous transaction. If the Update returns 0 Rows it can either be because the table is empty, or because two threads accessed the same row. - So we need a separate ending condition counting available rows.

```
-- Example if you CAN NOT use AQ or UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
LOOP
  -- ### autonomous transaction: (can be in its own method returning the id)
  BEGIN
    -- Mark a single ROW as being in processing...
    UPDATE test6 SET processed = 'L' WHERE processed = 'N' AND ROWNUM = 1 NOWAIT
    RETURNING id INTO l_id;
  EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN ... -- Can possibly fire if two threads access the same row...
    l_id := NULL;
  END
  -- ### end autonomous transaction;

  IF l_id IS NOT NULL THEN

    --DO BIG PROCESSING

    -- Mark the ROW is processed and DONE!
    UPDATE test6 SET processed = 'Y' WHERE id = l_id;

    COMMIT;
  END;

  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test6 WHERE processed = 'N' INTO rowsleft;
  EXIT IF rowsleft = 0;
END;
```